# Specifying parameters when creating a jQuery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm writing a jQuery plugin and I'm trying to set up a callback that takes a few parameters. How does jQuery determine which parameters are to be sent to a callback function?

In the plugin:

```
if (callback) {
    callback.call(var1, var2, var3);
}
```

The written callback:

```
$("#div").myplugin({callback: myfunction});
myfunction(biz,bar,bim) {
    alert("I love " + biz + " and " + bar + " and " + bim);
}
```

biz is set to var2, bar is set to var3, and bim is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of the `call` function is special:

```
fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

where `thisArg` is

> The value of `this` provided for the call to `fun`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

So, it would work if you passed a value for `thisArg`:

```
callback.call(this, var1, var2, var3);
```

Or, more simply, don't use `call` at all if you don't need `this` in the callback:

```
callback(var1, var2, var3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll find the answer in this [post](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx).

Basically there are several ways of achieving the goal you want. If you look down the post to the last example, you have an `args.push(arguments[i]);` line that may pass several parameters to the function using the only two arguments for the apply call.

As said here, the call method is similar, you have to put all the function arguments in the second parameter of the call method.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that post is great!